# ErrorPage class deprecated in Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: class, spring-boot, deprecated

In my working Spring Boot 1.4 application, I currently have

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ErrorPage;
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ErrorPage.html), as of 1.4 this class is deprecated in favor of `org.springframework.boot.web.ErrorPage`

However, when I change the code to

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.ErrorPage;
```

I get an error `The import org.springframework.boot.web.ErrorPage cannot be resolved`

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The javdoc's wrong. The correct replacement is `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ErrorPage`. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6764) so that we can fix the javadoc. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: This [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/deprecated-list.html) will also have to be fixed.

Comment: That's auto-generated so fixing the other one will fix this one too